# windows api ReadProcessMemorry() fail when I reuse this

Tags: windows, readprocessmemory

```
LPVOID pTargetNew = new LPVOID();
::ReadProcessMemory(hprocess,pBase,pTargetNew,4,&byred);
pBase = (LPVOID)((*pTargetNew) + 800);
::ReadProcessMemory(hprocess,pBase,pTargetNew,4,&byred);
pBase = (LPVOID)((*pTargetNew) + 24);
```

This is my code of the problem. After I calculate the pointer at the third line and start to invoke `ReadProcessMemory`, then I get `byred=0`. Why does the call fail?

I tried to change the code in c way.

```
int target = 0;`
LPVOID pTarget = (LPVOID)&target;
pBase = (LPVOID)(target + 800);
::ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, pBase, pTarget, 4, &byred);
pBase = (LPVOID)(target + 24);
::ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, pBase, pTarget, 4, &byred);
```

Then the code could run.

Comment: I think you need a much better understanding of pointers before using `ReadProcessMemory`.  The use of `LP` to hide pointers does not help, and the C casts prevent useful compiler warnings. As a result, `LPVOID pTargetNew = new LPVOID();` is hiding a subtle bug. `new LPVOID` is not a `LPVOID`, but an `LPVOID*`. (`void**` instead of `void*`. )